# Where did these lines of code memory leak in this ARC code?

Tags: ios, memory, memory-leaks, afnetworking

```
[client enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations:@[profileOperation,commFriendsOperation] progressBlock:^(NSUInteger finished, NSUInteger total){} completionBlock:^(NSArray *completedRequests){
//Code here
}]
```

The Code below are in an AFNetworking batch request success block. The instruments shows that codes blow have memory leak as it commented. However, I cannot figure out how did it leaked and how can I fix it, anybody has any idea?

Thanks in advance.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *commFriendsRequest = [completedRequests objectAtIndex:1];
    if(!commFriendsRequest.error&&commFriendsRequest.responseData){
        //Leak 46.2%
        NSDictionary *commDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:commFriendsRequest.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:NULL];
        int status1 = [[commDic objectForKey:@"status"]intValue];
        if(status1 == kSuccessCode){
            NSArray *commFriendsArray = [commDic objectForKey:@"data"];
            if(commFriendsArray&&commFriendsArray.count){
                //Leak 30.8%
                NSMutableArray *userItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:commFriendsArray.count];
                for(NSDictionary *dic in commFriendsArray){
                    //Leak 23.1%
                    userItem *item = [[userItem alloc]initFromServer:dic];
                    [userItems addObject:item];
                }
                if(profile){//Both Success
                    profile.commonFriends = userItems;
                    successBlock(profile);//block call back
                }else{
                    if(status0==kSuccessCode){
                        successBlock(userItems);//block call back
                    }else{
                        NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:kErrorDomain code:status0 userInfo:nil];
                        failedBlock(error);//block call back
                    }
                }
            }else if(status0==kSuccessCode){//CommFriends 0 has profile
                successBlock(profile);//block call back
            }
        }else{
            if(status0==kSuccessCode){//CommFriends failed has profile
                successBlock(profile);//block call back
            }else{//Both failed
                NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:kErrorDomain code:status1 userInfo:nil];
                failedBlock(error);//block call back
            }
        }
    }else{
        failedBlock(commFriendsRequest.error);
    }


//[[userItem alloc] initFromServer:dict] code
-(id)initFromServer:(NSDictionary *)dict{
if ((self = [super init])) {
    NSString *_userID = [dict objectForKey:@"userID"];
    NSString *_userName = [dict objectForKey:@"userName"];
    genderType _userGender = [[dict objectForKey:@"userGender"] integerValue];
    NSString *_userHeadImageURL = [dict objectForKey:@"userHeadImageURL"];
    NSString *_source = [dict objectForKey:@"source"];
    int _likeCount = [[dict objectForKey:@"likedCount"] intValue];
    int _sameFriends = [[dict objectForKey:@"sameFriends"] intValue];
    NSString *_homePage = [dict objectForKey:@"homePage"];

    NSString *_createTime = [dict objectForKey:@"createTime"];
    if([dict objectForKey:@"dis"])
        _distance = [[dict objectForKey:@"dis"]floatValue];
    else
        _distance = 0;

    if ([dict objectForKey:@"uid"]) {
        self.uid = [[dict objectForKey:@"uid"] intValue];
    }
    else{
        self.uid = -1;
    }

    self.userID = _userID;
    self.userName = _userName;
    self.userGender = _userGender;
    self.userHeadImageURL = _userHeadImageURL;
    self.source = _source;
    self.likeCount = _likeCount;
    self.sameFriends = _sameFriends;
    if (_homePage && ![_homePage isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
        self.homePage = _homePage;
    }

    if([dict objectForKey:@"hasJoin"]){
        self.hasJoined = [[dict objectForKey:@"hasJoin"]boolValue];
    }

    if (_createTime && ![_createTime isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"];
        self.createTime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:_createTime];
    }

    NSString *c = [dict objectForKey:@"comment"];
    if (c && ![c isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
        self.comment = c;
    }
}
return self;
```

}

Comment: Are you using ARC or not?

Comment: Sorry to add that, of cause ARC.

Comment: If not, leaks are much more than that

Comment: Please post the code to your `-(id)initFromServer` from class userDict, the leak might be in there.

Comment: @Cyrille I think it's not the initFromServer's problem, or the instruments would tell.

Comment: @Cyrille I added above, :)

Answer (score 0):

You should release object created by **alloc**, **copy**, **new** after add it to a container.  add message will increase the retain count.

```
//Leak 23.1%
userItem *item = [[userItem alloc]initFromServer:dic];  // [item retainCount] == 1 
[userItems addObject:item];  // [item retainCount] == 2
[item release];  // [item retainCount] == 1
```

if userItems is released, [item retainCount] == 0, and will be destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Note that Instruments tells you where a leaked object was allocated (because that helps you understand which object it is), but that doesn't mean the leak is at or near the allocation. The leak may be caused in some other code which over-retains or under-releases the object. You have to review the history of a specific leaked object (click the circled-arrow button next to an address) to see where a release was not balanced by a retain.

You're probably running this code on a background thread, and don't have an autorelease pool in place. ARC will still autorelease objects for you on occasion, and if you're calling into Apple frameworks, they may still be non-ARC, so they definitely could be autoreleasing objects for you. So you still need an autorelease pool in place.

**Cocoa creates an autorelease pool** for you on **the main thread**, but doesn't do anything for you on background threads. If you're going to kick something off onto a background thread without using NSOperation or something, **you'll want to wrap that thread in an @autoreleasepool, like so:**

```
- (void)doSomething {
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(backgroundSomething)];
}

- (void)backgroundSomething {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"Here I am in the background, doing something.");
        myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!I am using AFNetworking, it's using NSOperationQueue already. I am using this block pattern a lot of place, but it leaks only here, So I guess this problem might not the  autoreleasepool issue. AFNetwoking code is here:  https://iphone.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/Pods/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/AFHTTPClient.m